# How to use ImageMap clickable area at client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Has anyone used javascript, for ImageMap clickable parts? should be work in both IE and Firefox

Comment: Definitely it will work. Please post what have you tried.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for that at all. Just use [image maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.6) or [image inputs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1)

Comment: I have to also fill Color into clicked areas, like fillStyle,strokeStyle of context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use library for image map area selection. before that you have to create the map area of the image and use the library.

1) Mapper library

[Mapper Library](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/)

2) CVI Map Library

[CVI Map Library](http://code.dma.unipi.it/p/tentacles/browser/trunk/tentacles/public/js/mapper/cvi_map_lib.js?rev=11)

Comment: thanks, Nitin I found vectore graphics for IE and getContext method for Firefox in CVI Map javascript library